# python selenium to click a link

Tags: python, selenium

since I updated my firefox to 49.02 and selenium to 3.0.1, my previous code to sign in to my `bing account` does not work.

there is a `Sign in` link in `www.bing.com`, I could successfully click this link by calling:

```
driver.get("http://www.bing.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in').click()
```

however, after the upgrade, I receive a strange error message which contains no message at all:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
```

if I only call `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in')`, I will receive no error message. This seems like selenium could successfully locate this link, but somehow it can not click this button.

I have also tried to locate `Sign in` by it `class name` or by clicking the icon instead, but all such efforts are useless.

I do not know if the error is caused by Microsoft to block automated logging in or the error in my code. Helps appreciated!

calling `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[span = "Sign in"]').click()` as suggested by `alecxe` still does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do not use `implicit wait` as it's not working as expected, use `explicit wait` instead http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: Just to be sure I tested it in Selenium 2 and Chrome and can confirm the script is all right and the targeted element does exist.

Comment: @Andersson, yes, you are correct! once I switch to explicit wait as the result from `alecxe`, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the link *to be clickable*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
sign_in = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")))
sign_in.click()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I receive exactly the same error message

Comment: @user6651227 alright, please check the update. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested, using `XPATH` is just one way, but using `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in"))).click()` still gives me the expected result. So I am guessing there might be some other parts causes the problem. Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: @alecex, I know the reason, I should switch from implicit way to explicit wait as you did.

Comment: @user6651227 yeah, you are right, updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.